# Three.js - Find all Intersections on line Between Last and Current Mouse Position

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, collision-detection

Using Three.js, I have a scene with a bunch of lines. When the mouse moves, I use the standard raycaster method to check if the mouse is intersecting with any lines. This works fine if the mouse is moving slowly, but fails to handle the case where the mouse skips over a line because it is moving fast.

How would you find all the objects that intersect the screenspace line from the previous mouse position to the current mouse position using Three.js? Are there any builtin utilities that can help with this?

My current approach is to just take a bunch of samples on the line and test all of those using the raycaster, but that doesn't really fix the problem.

Comment: Try `raycaster.linePrecision = 10; // default is 1`

Comment: @WestLangley Won't that just mask the underlying problem, while also introducing false intersections?

Comment: False positives are possible. It was just a suggestion that may have been acceptable to you.

Answer (score 0):

trivial(low performance, but easy to code) approach is to create a plane(given by Rays from each of the mouse points)

check for intersections with Lines (= edges of your objects),

```
THREE.Plane.intersectLine()
```

then discard intersections that do not lie between rays given by mouse points

some easy heuristic to reduce number of candidate objects would be to consider only objects that have bounding sphere centers closer to the plane than the radius

```
THREE.Plane.distanceToPoint(sphereCenter) < sphereRadius
```

you have to combine this with traditional raycast at start and end point to catch object that have face larger than the end-start length